# No module named descartes even though it is installed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

[image]

I installed the package descartes with pip install descartes,
I received the ModuleNotFoundError, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it with pip3 since I am using python 3.8.

Still getting the error, using !pip freeze, I can see that it is there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/descartes/) looks like you don't need the `.path` in the import.

Comment: i also tried it only with 'import descartes'. I also installed other modules, here I have the same problem. The days before everything was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt installed jupyter in this environment^^